# What does "button is null" in Javascript mean?

Tags: javascript

I just started coding with JavaScript and i decided to run some code. (shown below)

```
var handleClick = function (event) {
    alert('Hello there!');
};
var button = document.querySelector('#big-button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

However, whenever I would run the code it would say the button is null. help?

Comment: if the `document.querySelector()` method cannot find a DOM element with an id of `big-button`, it will return `null`

Comment: Is there any element with id `big-button` in your DOM?

Comment: If you have a DOM element with `id="big-button"`, then you are probably just running this code too soon before the page has been parsed by the browser.  Put this code in a `<script>` tag at the end of the page.  This topic is discussed in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the/9899701#9899701

Answer (score 7):

From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> Returns null if no matches are found; otherwise, it returns the first matching element.

So, at the time you run `querySelector` there is no element in the DOM which has the ID *big-button*.

This is usually caused by putting the script in the `head` and trying to access elements in the `body`. Approaches to deal with this include:

- Moving the `<script>` so it appears after the element you are trying to access. This could be directly after it or just before the `</body>` tag.
- Wrap the code in a function and bind that function as a `load` event handler.
- Bind the event listener to the `window` and test `event.target` when the event fires to see if it matches the element.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, it means that the variable 'button' is null when you try and execute the line `button.addEventListener('click', handleClick)`.  This would happen if you don't have an element on the page when that code executes that has an id of 'big-button' which you're trying to retrieve with the call to `document.querySelector('#big-button');`

Answer (score 0):

Move your code inside the `onload` block

```
window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.querySelector('#big-button');
    button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="big-button">click me</button>
    <script>

        var handleClick = function (event) {
            alert('Hello there!');
        };
        var button = document.querySelector('#big-button');
        button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    </script>
```

Comment: A block of code with no explanation is pretty much never as good an answer as it could be with some explanation added.